# Is it possible to have a vector of tuples that are varying length?

Tags: rust

Something like this:

```
let vector = vec![(1, 2), ("A", 2, 3)];
```

If this isn't possible, what other alternatives could I use? For the sake of example, assume the length of the vector is unknown and the length of tuples is between 1 - 5 elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [enum](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/enums.html) with variants for each desired tuple length (and each allowed combination of component types if necessary).